# CFBundleDevelopmentRegion not works as expected

Tags: objective-c, macos, localization

I've added several localizations to my osx applications.

- English
- Simplified Chinese
- Traditional Chinese
- Italian
- French

and then trying to test other localization without change system language(default is English).

but no matter which language I set in the key `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` at `info.plist` file.
it always shows me the default (English) localization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-130430):

> CFBundleDevelopmentRegion (String -
>   iOS, Mac OS X) specifies the native
>   region for the bundle. This key
>   contains a string value that usually
>   corresponds to the native language of
>   the person who wrote the bundle. The
>   language specified by this value is
>   used as the default language if a
>   resource cannot be located for the
>   user’s preferred region or language.

All that it does is specify what language you developed it in (for if there's no localization for the user's default language). It does *not* change localization used to what you set it to, if that localization exists in your application. To test that you must change your locale in System Preferences.

Comment: wow, thanks. seems that I misunderstood the meaning of `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`. so, is there any simple way to test different localizations without change system's language? (or should I  post the question in a new thread?)

Comment: I'm not sure of one. Changing the system's language will only affect newly-launched applications, though, if that makes a difference.

Comment: The correct way of testing would be to actually change system language seeing as that's the way your users will go. Should be the best way of finding any problems.