# iOS7 app locale won't show Chinese app name and splash screens

Tags: objective-c, localization

An already existing iOS app of a client is now being localized for various languages.
I localized the storyboard, InfoPlist.strings, Localizable.strings, splash screens and icons.

For the English, Spanish and Dutch languages the app name gets translated, as well the settings screen.
However, for the Chinese languages (both Traditional and Simplified) the name of the app (as being displayed below the app icon and in settings) remains what is set by the base localize InfoPlist.strings The splash screens also won't change
Everything else (Storyboard, translating strings through code) gets translated as normally.
For the testing of the translations the simulator is being used.

This is in my InfoPlist.strings file for Chinese Simplified:
`"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Simplified";`
The file is located in `zh-Hans-CN.lproj` 
For the Traditional InfoPlist.strings file the content is similar, and the location is `zh-Hant-TW.lproj`
Both files were auto generated by Xcode 5.1
In the same directory the Localizable.strings are also present, and those files get loaded correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what language do you set in the simulator?

Comment: Chinese Simplified, If I'm not mistaken.  
Settings > General > International > Language > 4th item (5th is Traditional)

Comment: I'm actually quite sure that's correct, because everything else get translated like the settings screen, which I cannot control direct from code.

Comment: shouldn't be the folders names `zh-Hans.lproj` and `zh-Hant.lproj`? Maybe that's the issue. http://cl.ly/image/073Z2H0l3f3A  Not http://cl.ly/image/2z3y061a2i3K

Comment: lootsch, you're my hero! That was exactly the case, it seems that I mistakenly used region specific versions of Chinese Traditional and Chinese Simplified. If you could submit your comment as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Another related question: any idea what to use for CFBundleDevelopmentRegion so that UITabbarButtonItem get automatically translated when using Done, Add and other default buttons?

Comment: I don't think, this works as you expect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3536992/2115477

Comment: Please use the `xcode` tag only for questions related to the IDE itself.

Comment: Found the solution myself for `UITabbbarButtonItem` that wouldn't translate automatically after setting the language. Seems you also need to set `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"zh-Hant" forKey:@"preferredLocalizations"];`

Comment: "plutil -lint *" run in the directory of your zh-Hans.lproj can sometimes find issues not found through Xcode. I ran into a silent issue which did not cause any errors during compilation, but prevented my storyboard strings from appearing at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should localize for the general **Chinese** languages `zh-Hans.lproj` and `zh-Hant.lproj` not the special **Chinese Simplified (China)** and **Chinese Traditional (Taiwan)**